# OnKeyDown listener called 6 times for every key down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events, keyboard-events

I have added an `onKeyDown` event listener to the document of my component. It works, but it is called 6-7 times every key down event. It is very basic at this point, all I do is console log the event pretty much, so not sure what is done wrong exactly.

This is my component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const ActionButtons = ({ shuffleClick, keepClick }) => {
  const handleKeyDown = e => {
    console.log(e);
    console.log("this function was called")
  };

  componentDidMount(){

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  });

  return (
    <div className="flex-group-spaced-around small-margin-top">
      <div className="shuffler__button clickable" onClick={shuffleClick}>
        <p>Shuffle</p>
      </div>

      <div className="shuffler__button clickable" onClick={keepClick}>
        <p>Keep</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ActionButtons;
```

Comment: How many times is the `ActionButtons` component mounted on your page?

Comment: That the expected behaviour,  you might want keypress instead.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier you've pointed me to the right direction. I've added a cleanup function and now it is working just fine. If you'd like to add that as the answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @Keith to my understandin `keypress` is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ActionButton` component is probably mounted multiple times in your document. This means that for every `ActionButton` instance an event listener is registered on the document.

Rewrite your event handler to make sure that one a single global event is being listened to.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you use the React Hooks, your "componentDidMount()" should not here. And for your problem, "useEffect" is converting "componentDidMount()" and "componentDidUpdate()". So, may be it's because you don't finish your function, and "componentDidUpdate()" continue that.

Try this :

```js
useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
}, []);
```